# Create rows in sql join with overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, date, scd

I have two tables as below:

TableA

| ID | link1 | link2 | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | H | J | 1999-01-01 | 2005-01-01 |

TableB

| ID | link1 | link2 | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | X | Y | 2002-01-01 | 2008-01-01 |

And I want to query them and retreive the result below:

| ID | A.link1 | A.link2 | B.link1 | B.link2 | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | H | J |  |  | 1999-01-01 | 2002-01-01 |
| 99 | H | J | X | Y | 2002-01-02 | 2005-01-01 |
| 99 |  |  | X | Y | 2005-01-02 | 2008-01-01 |

It seems like I should be able to do this with sql using some kind of between join and perhaps some unions but I can't quite wrap my head around it. Can anyone tell me how can this result be produced please?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure you tag the DB you're using to get most accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in PostGreSQL:

```
SELECT a."id",
       a."link1",
       a."link2",
       NULL          AS link1,
       NULL          AS link2,
       a."date_from",
       b."date_from" AS DATE_TO
FROM   tab1 a
       left join tab2 b
              ON a."id" = b."id"
UNION ALL
SELECT a."id",
       a."link1",
       a."link2",
       b."link1",
       b."link2",
       b."date_from" + 1,
       a."date_to"
FROM   tab1 a
       join tab2 b
         ON a."id" = b."id"
UNION ALL
SELECT a."id",
       NULL            AS link1,
       NULL            AS link2,
       b."link1",
       b."link2",
       b."date_to" + 1 AS DATE_FROM,
       a."date_to"
FROM   tab2 a
       left join tab1 b
              ON a."id" = b."id";
```

Here's [SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oruCE2cWh65rLtMnHJQkDV/0) with output.

Comment: your SQL fiddle does not exactly match the desired result of the OP